# Cannot build circuits because we don't have enough directory information

Tags: bitcoinj, mac, java, tor

I'm developing a bitcoin wallet app using `BitcoinJ` framework. While deploying the app using `Tomcat 8`, I get the following stack of errors,

```
12-Jun-2017 14:18:12.511 INFO [PeerGroup Thread] com.subgraph.orchid.TorClient.start Starting Orchid (version: 1.0.0)

12-Jun-2017 14:18:12.514 INFO [Thread-12] com.subgraph.orchid.directory.DirectoryImpl.loadFromStore
Loading cached network information from disk

12-Jun-2017 14:18:12.516 INFO [Thread-12] com.subgraph.orchid.directory.DirectoryImpl.loadFromStore Loading certificates

12-Jun-2017 14:18:12.518 INFO [CircuitManager worker-0] com.subgraph.orchid.circuits.CircuitCreationTask.checkCircuitsForCreation
Cannot build circuits because we don't have enough directory information

12-Jun-2017 14:18:12.601 INFO [Thread-12] com.subgraph.orchid.directory.DirectoryImpl.loadFromStore Loading consensus

12-Jun-2017 14:18:12.917 WARNING [Thread-12] com.subgraph.orchid.directory.consensus.ConsensusDocumentImpl.verifySingleAuthority
Consensus signed by unrecognized directory authority: 0232af901c31a04ee9848595af9bb7620d4c5b2e

12-Jun-2017 14:18:12.943 INFO [Thread-12] com.subgraph.orchid.directory.DirectoryImpl.loadFromStore Loading
microdescriptor cache

12-Jun-2017 14:18:13.160 INFO [Thread-12] com.subgraph.orchid.directory.DirectoryImpl.loadFromStore loading state file

12-Jun-2017 14:18:15.662 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying
web application directory [/Applications/Tomcat-8.5.15/webapps/manager]
```

The last 2 lines of the stack,

```
org.bitcoinj.core.PeerGroup: 06/12/2017 14:53:36 - Tor ready
org.bitcoinj.core.PeerGroup: 06/12/2017 14:53:36 - Localhost peer not detected.
```

I believe `Tomcat` deployment is fine and one of the errors is crucial informing -`com.subgraph.orchid.circuits.CircuitCreationTask.checkCircuitsForCreation Cannot build circuits because we don't have enough directory information`

I use maven as the build tool and get the RELEASE version of the `BitcoinJ` as dependency in the project.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bitcoinj</groupId>
    <artifactId>bitcoinj-core</artifactId>
    <version>RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I recently loaded `RAM` in the system and upgraded to the `OS Sierra`. I had the surprise, I couldn't use maven from the terminal afterwards and set that up manually. Current Maven information,

```
$ mvn -version

Apache Maven 3.5.0 (ff8f5e7444045639af65f6095c62210b5713f426; 2017-04-04T01:39:06+06:00)
Maven home: /Users/Chaklader/apache-maven-3.5.0
Java version: 1.8.0_131, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.12.4", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

How to approach to the problem properly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cannot build circuits because we don't have enough directory information

This is an exact duplicate of a standard Tor error message usually only seen for brief periods after Tor node startup.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by itself. I guess the info `Localhost peer not detected` was behind the scene. Now, after finding the `peers` I have the app synchronized to the `blockchain`

[image]